# How to gain mental strength?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit, shloka, stotra, mind

**Any Mantras, Shlokas, Stotras** related to gain mental strength, overcome mental disorders.

Which God is related to mind, related to these mental aspects like mental strength, mind related disorders.

Which God would you pray in a situation, where everyone is your enemy, playing mind games, deceiving others to hate you..etc..

**Are there any practices in Hinduism** related to **Mental Strength?**

There should be some scriptures in Hinduism which deals in detail with mental disorders, like depression, mental weakness etc, and how to overcome them..

Previously I used to say Let everyone be happy – In English..
But then I started saying  this Sloka, after learning it:

ॐ सर्वे भवन्तु सुखिनः सर्वे सन्तु निरामयाः|

सर्वे भद्राणि पश्यन्तु मा कश्चिद् दुःखभाग् भवेत् ||

So I strongly believe that Sanskrit words and Sanskrit phrases have effect on my mind..

**Please write some Sanskrit Phrases, Shlokas** which will help me in mental toughness.

What Sanskrit affirmations (probably recommended in Scriptures) should I tell Myself every morning?

Please give Specific, detailed answer with Script reference if possible..

Comment: Chant and remember the name of god, he does only whatever is good for his devotees.

Comment: ☺, Please write some Sanskrit verse, hymns..anything.. It will help me..

Comment: Is there any mantra, shloka for Good Relationship with People, (Family Members)...they are really toxic, always put blame one me, Im their scapegoat, emotionally harassed.

Comment: See mantras are not like mathematical formulas or medical prescriptions - take haldi helps in sore throat. God is not a doctor. Merely taking the name of god relieves people from their problems and makes them realise things.

Comment: I try to be Good behaviour, when talking with my Family member, but they, always take My advantage.. Chanting Mantra gives Me hope..

Comment: Visit a counsellor

Comment: lockdown, no money, no good counsellors...

Comment: You can use white pearl stone for mind disorders like anxiety, practice mental hygiene and morning meditation and avoiding intoxicating drinks or smoking.

Comment: @Rickross How to gain mental strength?

Comment: @Rickross ??????

Comment: What is your definition of mental strength?

Answer (score 2):

Bhagavad Gita 6.5:

> “उद्धरेदात्मनात्मानं नात्मानमवसादयेत् । आत्मैव ह्यात्मनो बन्धुरात्मैव रिपुरात्मनः ॥

“One should lift up oneself by oneself. One should not let oneself get depressed or defeated - because the self is the friend of oneself and the self is the enemy of oneself”

Answer (score 2):

What nothing can do, faith does. Many of the mantras to say in layman's term act as positive affirmations. But, I rather keep Science away from spirituality as there's nothing to prove in spiritual aspects as everything is based.
Now, simply the practice of faith and devotion will do the wonders, what even tranquilizers couldn't. We all know the story of the middle school "last leaf". So, faith not just gives peace, but it takes everyone near to their isht. All sadhanas r just blabbering some mantras if devoid of faith.

Now as you said,Vishnu is your isht, I shall quote some beautiful lines from his stotras.

Hari Stotra-

> Bhambhoditheeram Bajeham Bajeham।
> I worship (that Hari who) takes you across the sea of life.
> Swabakthanukoolam jagadvrukshamoolam, Nirastharthasoolam Bajeham Bajeham।
> I worship (that Hari) Who is very partial to his devotees(always stand by them even if they are fallen),
> Who is the root of the tree of the world,
> And is the exterminator of all sorrows.

The fhalshruti of this stotram says,

> Savishnor vishokam druvam yathilokam,
> Jarajanmasokam punar vidathe no.
> (Those who read this stotra) would definitely reach the world of Vishnu,
> Which is always without sorrow
> And he would never undergo sorrow ever.

So, when a person is getting salokya by mere chanting of a stotram, why think more!

Narayana stotram-

> Narayanapātakarajanīsaṁhāra karuṇālaya māmuddhara nārāyaṇa।।
> Oh lord who destroys the darkness of sin, Oh Lord who elevates me by his mercy,Narayana.
>
> acalōddhr̥ticañcatkara bhaktānugrahatatpara nārāyaṇa ||
> Oh Lord who was able to lift a mountain, Oh Lord who is interested in blessing devotes, Narayana.

Rama Ashtakam-

> स्वभक्तभीतिभञ्जनं भजे ह राममद्वयम् ॥
> I worship that Lord, who frees his devotees from fear and bestows on them a peaceful mind.
>
> समं शिवं निरञ्जनं भजे ह राममद्वयम् ॥
> The one who sees and treats everyone equally, and does everything that is ultimately beneficial to his devotees,I worship such Lord Ràma.
> शिवप्रदं सुखप्रदं भवच्छिदं भ्रमापहम् ।
> विराजमानदेशिकं भजे ह राममद्वयम् ॥
> I worship Lord Rama, who brings prosperity and happiness to his devotees, despite being free of all indulgences. I worship one who destroys the illusion of mind. I worship Lord Rama, who is second to none.

Ramcharit manas-

> जा पर कृपा राम की होई। ता पर कृपा करहिं सब कोई॥
> The one who are blessed by Ràm, everyone blesses him.

It says, if your blessed by Ràm, every deity blesses you, everyone around you in the samasara works as per your desire, and thus you feel as those people too are blessing you.

> इहि सोइ जो राम रचि राखा।
> को करि तर्क बढ़ावै साखा॥
> Whatever Ràm has thought and planned for you, only that will happen. By, trying to find logic who wants to increase (the debate).

Here, Tulsidasji says it all upto my lord, what he has planned so shall happen inevitably. Thus, he says he don't want to debate over it, as he has such firm faith on lord. And the point to note is that, the Isht deity every does anything bad for their bhakta. So, he is completly at peace.

This one is the ultimate one, which gives the sense of free from all karma, depression, etc.

> कायेन वाचा मनसेन्द्रियैर्वा । बुद्ध्यात्मना वा प्रकृतिस्वभावात् ।।
> करोमि यद्यत्सकलं परस्मै । नारायणयेति समर्पयामि ॥
> (Whatever I do) with my Body, Speech, Mind or Sense Organs,
> (Whatever I do) using my Intellect, Feelings of Heart or (unconsciously) through the natural tendencies of my Mind,
> Whatever I do, I do all for others,
> I Surrender them all at the Lotus Feet of Sri Narayana.

When we have completly surrendered to his feet, there's no worry for us. Then, it's just,**"इहि सोइ जो राम रचि राखा।"**
Thus you must read various ashtakams on Shree Hari, Narayana Stotram, Hari Stotram. All this will not only increase faith but truly gives peace and mental tranquility that we have our back on Shree Hari and apart from all the most important it helps one to get closer to the isht.

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Answer (score 1):

The Blessed Lord said: Fearlessness, purification of one's existence, cultivation of spiritual knowledge, charity, self-control, performance of sacrifice, study of the Vedas, austerity and simplicity; nonviolence, truthfulness, freedom from anger; renunciation, tranquility, aversion to faultfinding, compassion and freedom from covetousness; gentleness, modesty and steady determination; vigor, forgiveness, fortitude, cleanliness, freedom from envy and the passion for honor-these transcendental qualities, O son of Bharata, belong to godly men endowed with divine nature.

Arrogance, pride, anger, conceit, harshness and ignorance-these qualities belong to those of demonic nature, O son of Prtha.

The transcendental qualities are conducive to liberation, whereas the demonic qualities make for bondage. Do not worry, O son of Pandu, for you are born with the divine qualities.
O son of Prtha, in this world there are two kinds of created beings. One is called the divine and the other demonic. I have already explained to you at length the divine qualities. Now hear from Me of the demoniac.

Those who are demoniac do not know what is to be done and what is not to be done. Neither cleanliness nor proper behavior nor truth is found in them.

They say that this world is unreal, that there is no foundation and that there is no God in control. It is produced of sex desire, and has no cause other than lust.

Following such conclusions, the demoniac, who are lost to themselves and who have no intelligence, engage in unbeneficial, horrible works meant to destroy the world.

The demoniac, taking shelter of insatiable lust, pride and false prestige, and being thus illusioned, are always sworn to unclean work, attracted by the impermanent.

They believe that to gratify the senses unto the end of life is the prime necessity of human civilization. Thus there is no end to their anxiety. Being bound by hundreds and thousands of desires, by lust and anger, they secure money by illegal means for sense gratification.

The demoniac person thinks: So much wealth do I have today, and I will gain more according to my schemes. So much is mine now, and it will increase in the future, more and more. He is my enemy, and I have killed him; and my other enemy will also be killed. I am the lord of everything, I am the enjoyer, I am perfect, powerful and happy. I am the richest man, surrounded by aristocratic relatives. There is none so powerful and happy as I am. I shall perform sacrifices, I shall give some charity, and thus I shall rejoice. In this way, such persons are deluded by ignorance.

Thus perplexed by various anxieties and bound by a network of illusions, one becomes too strongly attached to sense enjoyment and falls down into hell.

Self-complacent and always impudent, deluded by wealth and false prestige, they sometimes perform sacrifices in name only without following any rules or regulations.

Bewildered by false ego, strength, pride, lust and anger, the demon becomes envious of the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who is situated in his own body and in the bodies of others, and blasphemes against the real religion.

Those who are envious and mischievous, who are the lowest among men, are cast by Me into the ocean of material existence, into various demoniac species of life.

Attaining repeated birth amongst the species of demoniac life, such persons can never approach Me. Gradually they sink down to the most abominable type of existence.

There are three gates leading to this hell-lust, anger, and greed. Every sane man should give these up, for they lead to the degradation of the soul.

The man who has escaped these three gates of hell, O son of Kunti, performs acts conducive to self-realization and thus gradually attains the supreme destination.

But he who discards scriptural injunctions and acts according to his own whims attains neither perfection, nor happiness, nor the supreme destination.

One should understand what is duty and what is not duty by the regulations of the scriptures. Knowing such rules and regulations, one should act so that he may gradually be elevated

Comment: Please write some Sanskrit Phrases

Comment: @HinduKid which god are you devoted to?

Comment: Devote to Vishnu

Comment: @HinduKid then Take a beautiful Image or an idol of Lord Vishnu and place it toward the east and always place in a way you should have His feet in front of you while sitting , never looking down to it, but up .Burn some incense.  Make prostrations  in front of Him (not bowing or prostrate like a woman, but full prostrations with all your body) as much as you can. While sitting in front of Him recite this mantra :  ॐ नमो भगवते वासुदेवाय for at least one hour a day for at least three months. You will obtain what are you searching for.

Comment: Om Namo Bhagavate Vasudevaya means: “Om, I bow to Lord Vasudeva or Lord Krishna”
This twelve syllable mantra is known as a Mukti (liberation) mantra and a spiritual formula for attaining freedom.

“ सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज ।
अहं त्वां सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुचः ॥१८- ६६॥”
Relinquishing everything else and all ideas of righteousness surrender unto me (Krishna) exclusively.
I (Krishna) will deliver you from all sins (sinful reactions), do not despair.

Comment: Krishna also proclaimed “Everybody should recite “Om Namo Bhagavate Vasudevaya” mantra daily whenever possible so that I will stand by them. I respond to the call of the heart immediately and invariably. See me in your duties. I am committed to those who are committed to their duties. Believe in putting faith in me and make me your own”.

Comment: Sorry , i modified according to the Gita since you are devoted to Lord Vishnu. Practice for your welfare and for  the welfare of all sentient beings.

Comment: Beautifully written, Can you write Sanskrit version of it.. I have added few requests in my questions, please read it..

Comment: It is the chapter 16 of the Gita. God is one , whatever  aspect you worship.